# Same method name with EnumSet (of different type) as a parameter

Tags: java, android, eclipse, deprecated, enumset

I have a method A

```
@Deprecated
public void doSomething (EnumSet <TypeA> param){

}
```

Now, I want to write a new method B such that it has a same signature but takes an EnumSet of different type.

```
public void doSomething(EnumSet <TypeB> param){

}
```

When I do that, eclipse gives me an error of same erasure. Is there a way to solve this purpose ? 
Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Because of type erasure, both of those methods are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the method with an `EnumSet<SomeType>` the identity of `SomeType` undergoes erasure and is not known. You need to accept an instance of `SomeType` or `Class<SomeType>` to avoid erasure:

```
private void doSomethingA(EnumSet<TypeA>){ ... }

private void doSomethingA(EnumSet<TypeA>){ ... }

private void <T extends Enum<T>> doSomething(EnumSet<T extends BaseType> s, T tInst){
    if(t instanceof TypeA) doSomethingA(s);
    if(t instanceof TypeB) doSomethingB(s);
}
```

For readability, I use `T` and `t` but it could be written as:

```
private void <SOMETYPE extends Enum<SOMETYPE>> doSomething(EnumSet<SOMETYPE> s, SOMETYPE instanceOfSomeType){
    if(instanceOfThatType instanceof TypeA) doSomethingA(s);
    if(instanceOfThatType instanceof TypeB) doSomethingB(s);
}
```

Note that `SOMETYPE` and `T` are written as-is. They are placeholders at runtime, but literal at the time of writing the code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you mean by "T" and "t"

Comment: @user2453055 `T` is a generic type declared to extend `Enum<T>`(i.e. it is an an enum type). `t` is just the name of a variable. I could write this as `private void <SOMETYPE extends Enum<SOMETYPE>> doSomething(.... SOMETYPE instanceOfThatType){`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much. 

*Upvote: But requires 15 reputation* :(

Answer (score 2):

Since Java compiler has type erasure, the runtime type information is unknown.

What actually happens is that both methods are compiled to

```
public void doSomething(EnumSet<Object> param)
```

hence you have two methods with the same signature, this is obviously incorrect since the JDK couldn't decide which one to invoke. You could just name them differently or use a different upper bound.

According to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) behavior:

> Replace all type parameters in generic types **with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded**. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.